# Working pattern for 2 web developers

Tags: design-patterns

What would be the best working pattern for 2 web developers working on same project simultaneously. At the moment i am working with my co dev and we have a web server and both our ides are just uploading our changes and if he made changes before me ide just warns me and lets merge those files that conflict.
I know there version control systems but i cant get a grip on where to start with them and how to set it up for our needs in terms of organizational pattern. The main thing is that when we code together we need fast updates on the files we are editing, its not like we do separate parts for whole day and at the end we merge them, its small pieces constantly updating.

What are you suggestions good people?

PS we are using PHPStorm from JetBrains as our IDEs.

Answer (score 0):

> where to start with vesion control

you can use open source source control like `git` or `svn`. `git` is popular these days.
Here is link for setup http://git-scm.com/book/en/Getting-Started-First-Time-Git-Setup

> when we code together we need fast updates on the files we are editing

well as per my knowledge , no version control software `pushes` the changes to your workspace.  you will have to `pull` them frequently if you want to have updated copy. So for your case, as both of you need to share changes frequently, push the every small modular change once done. If you are using `git` , u'll be forced everytime to pull latest changes first, so automatically u'll have latest copy of file everytime u commit
Note: make sure u commit modular change, so that reverting becomes easy.

Comment: You may be able to set up hooks on the central repository to push to all of the individual repositories. I don't know how useful this would be, though.